# Regex works everywhere else except sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to figure out why my regex works in every other scripting language but not when I pipe a webpage into sed with the same expression.

I'm running this:

`wget -qO- http://website.com/page.html | sed -n '/([0-9]+)(?=%<\/td>)/g'`

I'm looking for all digits preceding the last occurence of "%</td>".

The regex works in PHP, Python, Ruby, and javascript, but in sed, it returns nothing at all.

How can I get that regex to work in sed?

Comment: @anubhava doh! okay. Does awk or grep? Or would I have to rethink the expression

Comment: You are looking for `grep` - `grep -oP '[0-9]+(?=%</td>)'` perhaps.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew awesome. that did the trick. Feel free to post that as answer. worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` is mostly used for removing/replacing strings in files. Since you need to *extract* matches, `grep` should come handy, especially with the `-P` option that allows you to use PCRE regex patterns (that allow both lookbehinds and lookaheads).

So, in your case, you may use

```
grep -oP '[0-9]+(?=%</td>)'
```

The `-o` option will output the matches only, and `-P` will enable PCRE regex engine parsing the pattern.

A test on Ubuntu 14 and a file that only has `<td>word 15%</td><td>word 85%</td><td>word 6%</td><td>word 1865%</td>` line:

[image]

Comment: I had tried earlier with grep and wasn't aware of the `-P` switch, which was why the lookahead wasn't working then either. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All tools support specific regexp variants and some have additional caveats and some tools support different flavors depending on what arguments you pass to them.

`sed` supports BREs by default, and some seds (GNU and OSX) also support EREs when enabled with `-E` but none support PCREs.

`grep` supports BREs by default, EREs when enabled with `-E`, and PCREs when enabled with `-P`. It's worth mentioning, though, that `-P` is GNU grep only and as their man page says that functionality is `highly experimental` so YMMV with using it.

`awk` only supports EREs.

I THINK `perl` only supports PCREs but you'd have to check the man page.

Given sample input and expected output we could show you how to do what you want without needing a PCRE but in lieu of that - at a guess it sounds like all you need is:

```
sed 's:.*\([0-9]*\)%</td>.*:\1:'
```

which would work in all seds on all UNIX boxes.